# Socket constructor issue in node.js

Tags: node.js

I have following code in node.js.

```
const express = require("express");
var socket = require("socket.io");

class Server {

    constructor() {
        this.app = express();
        this.port = process.env.PORT || 89;
        this.host = process.env.HOST || `192.168.43.173:89`;
    }

    includeRoutes() {
    }

    appExecute() {

        var server = this.app.listen(this.port, () => {
            console.log(`Listening on http://${this.host}`);
        });     
        var io = socket(server);
    }
}
const server = new Server();
server.appExecute();
```

below are the dependencies exist in **package.json** file.

```
"express": "^4.17.1",
"socket.io": "^2.3.0"
```

I am facing an issue when the line is executed `var io = socket(server);`

Error Details.

> Unexpected Token ...options.

**Here is the screenshot.**

[image]

Can you please suggest something? If you need more info, please let me know

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Upgrade Node.js to a current version, or use the `--harmony` flag when starting it.

The `...` is an ES6 [spread operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax), and is supported normally in current versions of Node.js.

See also:  https://nodejs.org/en/docs/es6/

Comment: great answer but i think it would be better if it includes a brief `how to update` :D

Comment: Thank You very much, Everything works perfectly after installing the latest version of node.js.

Comment: @mAhMoUdDaFeR Literally just have to go to the Node.js website, click the big green download button, and run the installer.